# Add one to every value in a column each time that it exceeds the numbers in a set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rank

I'm dealing with a ranking crisis. Imagine some data like this:

| Data | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 10 |
| Bob | 25 |
| Claire | 33 |
| Dale | 42 |
| Ebony | 56 |
| Fed | 68 |

And imagine that I have a set of values: 13, 35, and 49. I want to go through my set of ranks and add one to each rank for each time that it exceeds a value in this set. This means that my final output will be worked out as:

| Data | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 10 + 0 = 10 |
| Bob | 25 + 1 = 26 |
| Claire | 33 + 1 = 34 |
| Dale | 42 + 2 = 44 |
| Ebony | 56 + 3 = 59 |
| Fed | 68 + 3 = 71 |

How can this be achieved? I don't want to write a cursor unless I really have to. I suspect that joins can solve this somehow.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` to the other table and then add the `COUNT` to your `Rank` column?

Comment: @Larnu Very smart! That'll probably work. I overlooked `COUNT`. Draft that up as an answer and you've probably got it straight away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling in the blanks a little, but I *assume* you could likely just use a `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT` here:

```sql
SELECT YT.Data,
       YT.Rank + COUNT(OT.OtherValue) AS Rank
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN dbo.OtherTable OT ON YT.Rank > OT.Othervalue
GROUP BY YT.Data,
         YT.Rank;
```